# Business Object properties: model as Objects or Enums?

Tags: c#, oop

If I want to represent status types i.e .

1. started
2. in progress
3. completed
   etc.

I know I can use `Enum`'s in normal code but how should i represent them in the business objects layer, as objects or as enums, I am thinking about whether to use static classes?

any advice would be appreciated.

A context example would be I have new job business object and it has a status of inprogress when retrieved.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: enums are meant for this sort of requirement

Comment: What exactly is "normal code"?

Answer (score 5):

You should probably use enums. It would be the clearest solution. For example:

```
public enum JobStatus
{
    Started,
    InProgress,
    Completed
}


public class Job
{
   public JobStatus GetStatus()
   {
       // Obviously, you would probably check some conditions here
       // and return the proper status. 
       return JobStatus.Started;
   }
}
```